# Migrate SQL Server Database from Rackspace cloud to Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have SQL Server Database in Rackspace Cloud. I want to migrate the SQL DB from Rackspace to Microsoft Azure cloud. How can I do this ? Please help me.

Thanks,
Vishwajeet.

Comment: This is out of scope for SO. This should be posted in `serverfault.stackexchange.com` or `dba.stackexchange.com`. SO is for questions related to programming

Answer (score 3):

There is [a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate) about Migrating SQL server database to Azure.

So, We can use **Data Migration Assistant** to [migrating your SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database) esily. You can refer to this tutorial to migrate your SQL server database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, @VishwajeetMCA . If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer to help more  people. Thanks!